# Check if two consectutive characters are in a list

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

```
prblm = input("Input the Blackout math problem: ")
#I'm using  2//4=5 

OP = ['+', '-', '*', '/']  

def validate():

    """Checks to see if a string is valid"""
        for c in prblm:
            if c in OP and c+1 in OP:
                print('a')
```

when run it displayes:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

it should print out 'a'

How do I fix the function to work or how do I check if two consecutive characters are in the list?

Comment: If you find a solution to your problem, just post it as an answer, don't paste it over your original question

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ord` and `chr` functions to get the subsequent character:

```
def validate():
    """Checks to see if a string is valid"""
        for c in prblm:
            if c in OP and chr(ord(c)+1) in OP:
                print('a')
```

Comment: I tried it, there are no errors, but it fails to print a

Comment: Are you inputting data that contains two separate characters?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @AlexCampbell in an edit to his question:

> ```
> prblm = input("Input the Blackout math problem: ")
> #I'm using  2//4=5 
>
> OP = ['+', '-', '*', '/']  
>
> def validate():
>
>     """Checks to see if a string is valid"""
>         for c in range (0, len(prblm)-2):
>             if c in OP and c+1 in OP:
>                 print('a')
> ```
>
> Fixed it. Had to use range function. before: c was an el now: using c
>   as in iterator